# When deleting the login page, I still get the old middleware configuration on auth js - nuxt version 2.15.7

Tags: nuxt.js

point is I decided to delete the login page that was inside pages "/login". Because I wanted to change the name and have it under a folder called "auth" to keep a better file order. I deleted the nuxt folder and I ran again the dev command to rebuild, but I noticed that I still was redirect to the /login page, I did search where that was coming, and ended up that the auth.js inside nuxt have a configuration redirect still pointing out /login, so no matter how many times I delete the folder .nuxt is still reappearing even if the page does not exist anymore.

What I also did was:

- Remove the middleware config completely from nuxt.config.js
- Delete the middleware folder
- Delete again the .nuxt folder

But still I will have this configuration on the auth.js file

```js
export default function (ctx, inject) {
  // Options
  const options = {
  "resetOnError": false,
  "ignoreExceptions": false,
  "scopeKey": "scope",
  "rewriteRedirects": true,
  "fullPathRedirect": false,
  "watchLoggedIn": true,
  "redirect": {
    "login": "/login",
    "logout": "/",
    "home": "/",
    "callback": "/login"
  },
  "vuex": {
    "namespace": "auth"
  },
  "cookie": {
    "prefix": "auth.",
    "options": {
      "path": "/"
    }
  },
  "localStorage": {
    "prefix": "auth."
  },
  "defaultStrategy": ""
}
```

Any ideas for a workaround? Is this a type of bug, or do I'm missing something?

**** UPDATE nuxt.config.js ******

```js
export default {
   
    target: 'static',
    head: {
      title: 'test',
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'en'
      },
      meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
        { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
      ]
    },
  
 
    css: [
      '~/assets/css/font.css',
      '~/assets/css/base.css',
      '~/assets/css/forms.css'
    ],
  

    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/vee-validate.js'
    ],
  

    components: true,
  
  
    buildModules: [
     
    ],
  
  
    modules: [
      '@nuxtjs/axios',
      '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
    ],

  firebase:{
    config: {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    services: {
      auth: {
        persistence: 'local',
        initialize: {
          onAuthStateChangedAction: 'authentication/onAuthStateChangedAction',
          subscribeManually: false
        },
        ssr: false, 
      }
    }
  },
  axios:{
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
  auth: {
  
  },
  router:{
  },
 
    build: {
    transpile: ['vee-validate']
    }
  }
```

Comment: `.nuxt` is indeed a caching directory. If you have some code that is coming back, you probably missed something. Did you looked for the `router` key in your `nuxt.config.js` file? Also, could you please link the whole file from there please? Also, be sure to test this in a incognito window just to be sure that this is not related to cache or something alike.

Comment: Hello kissu, thank you for the answer, I just updated the code above with nuxt.config.js I also tried in incognito mode, before I just forgot to mentioned it

Comment: If you're not planning to use `auth`, remove it from the config file. Then, tell us if you still have an issue.

Comment: Hello Kissu, thank you for the answer, so I deleted the auth:[] but still was getting the same config, so I deleted as well the router(because at the beginning i had a middleware config under) and by deleting the last one and rebuild, the old config disappeared. So thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP had trouble removing some old `nuxt/auth` configuration, by deleting the `auth` keys in `nuxt.config.js`, the router and cleaning `.nuxt`, the issue was then solved!